# Is (topology, union, empty set) with basis as generator a monoid?

Tags: general-topology, monoid

- Set - $\tau $
- Generator -  basis of $\tau $
- Operator - $\cup $
- Unit - empty set

Is it a monoid?

Comment: Is every basis for the topology closed under finite unions?

Comment: @AlexKruckman Does a generator also has to be closed under union?

Comment: What do you mean by a generator?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid#Generators @AlexKruckman

Comment: The question does not really make sense. A topology with union *is* a monoid (just like any family of sets containing $\emptyset$ and closed under finite union), but it has nothing to do with the basis. The basis of a topology *is not* in general a generating set for the topology (because not every open set is a finite union of basic open sets).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

A base for a topological space is not necessarily closed under union. For instance, the set of open intervals is a base for the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$, but the set of open intervals is not closed under union.

However, if the base is closed under union, then it should be a monoid, since set union is an associative operation.

Comment: Do you mean that generator also has to be closed under union?

Comment: I understood you question as "Is the base of a topological space a monoid under union?" If you ask something else, you'll have to rephrase your question.